# How to solve the convex optimization problem with complex variables by ADMM?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
     &\arg\min_{C} \frac{1}{2}c^HAc+\lambda\|C\|_{*}\\
         &s.t. C_{i,j}=M_{i,j}.
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

where $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a Hermite matrix, $c$ is a complex variable which is the vectorization of $C\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ . How to solve this problem by ADMM? I see some references in real variable condition which is not the same as in complex condition, such as the derivatives of complex variables.

Comment: Your objective function includes the variable $C$ as well as what looks like another variable vector $c$.  Is $c=C$?  Is $c$ a constant?  Something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have rewritten the problem above.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the following article, which describes an elegant framework for employing ADMM to minimize a real function in complex variables:
https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2015/104531/abs/